# Avoid throwing a new exception

Tags: exception

I have an **if** condition which checks for value and the it throws new **NumberFormatException**

Is there any other way to code this

```
if (foo)
{
    throw new NumberFormatException
}

// ..

catch (NumberFormatException exc)
{
    // some msg...
}
```

Comment: Might want to use the 'code' markup to make your question a little clearer to read.

Comment: This question is not very clear you need to rephrase your question

Comment: GustlyWind, my brain just threw QuestionUnreableException. Please clarify.

Comment: @Midhat: no, but there's throe in the try. :-(

Comment: What language? Java? C#?

Comment: @Patrik Looks like Java. Good `catch`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing something such as this:

```
try
{
   // some stuff
   if (foo)
   {
      throw new NumberFormatException();
   }
}
catch (NumberFormatException exc)
{
   do something;
}
```

Then sure, you could avoid the exception completely and do the 'do something' part inside the conditional block.

Answer (score 3):

If your aim is to avoid to throw a new exception:

```
if(foo)
{
  //some msg...
} else
{
  //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't throw exceptions if you can handle them in another, more elegant manner.  Exceptions are expensive and should only be used for cases where there is something going on beyond your control (e.g. a database server is not responding).

If you are trying to ensure that a value is set, and formatted correctly, you should try to handle failure of these conditions in a more graceful manner.  For example...

```
if(myObject.value != null && Checkformat(myObject.Value)
{
    // good to go
}
else
{
    // not a good place to be.  Prompt the user rather than raise an exception?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can try parsing a string with regular expressions before trying to convert it to a number.

If you're trying to catch your own exception (why???) you could do this:

```
try { if (foo) throw new NumberFormatException(); }
catch(NumberFormatexception) {/* ... */}
```

Comment: You could have fit more code on one line. It's still way to readable (note: sarcasm). :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to replace the throwing of an exception with some other error handling mechanism your only option is to return or set an error code - the problem is that you then have to go and ensure it is checked elsewhere.

the exception is best.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the flow that will cause you to throw a NumberFormatException, code to handle that case.  You shouldn't use Exception hierarchies as a program flow mechanism.